# How to check if all elements of a vector are in a list, adding a column with the name of the list where this occurs (in R)

Tags: r, list

I have a List with "N" data frames (all with the same number of fixed rows and columns, and some values ​​could be NA) which looks like this:

```
   A1<-c(1:5)
   A2<-c(3)
   A3<-c(1:2)
   A4<-c(1:3)
   A5<-as.integer(c(NA))
   
   length(A1)<-5
   length(A2)<-5
   length(A3)<-5
   length(A4)<-5
   length(A5)<-5
   
   DF1 <- data.frame(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)
   
   B1<-c(4:8)
   B2<-c(5)
   B3<-c(1:2)
   B4<-c(8:12)
   B5<-c(1)
   
   length(B1)<-5
   length(B2)<-5
   length(B3)<-5
   length(B4)<-5
   length(B5)<-5
   
   DF2 <- data.frame(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
   
   LIST <- list(DF1,DF2)
   names(LIST) <- c("DF1","DF2")

DF1
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1  1  3  1  1 NA
2  2 NA  2  2 NA
3  3 NA NA  3 NA
4  4 NA NA NA NA
5  5 NA NA NA NA

DF2
  B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
1  4  5  1  8  1
2  5 NA  2  9 NA
3  6 NA NA 10 NA
4  7 NA NA 11 NA
5  8 NA NA 12 NA
```

I have another dataframe with N rows and 5 columns and for each row I would like to check if the element of each column is contained in the corresponding column in the list objects. If all elements are contained, I would like to add a column with the name of the dataframe in which this occurred.

Dataframe I would like to check:

```
   row1 <- c(4,3,1,3,NA)
   row2 <- c(5,5,1,10,1)
   row3 <- c(5,2,2,3,NA)
   
   DataBase <- data.frame(rbind(row1,row2,row3))

     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
row1  4  3  1  3 NA
row2  5  5  1 10  1
row3  5  2  2  3 NA
```

So for row1, I would like to check if the element of column X1 (4) is contained in columns A1 or B1, element of column X2 (3) is contained in columns A2 or B2 and so on. So the expected result would be:

```
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 Result
row1  4  3  1  3 NA DF1
row2  5  5  1 10  1 DF2
row3  5  2  2  3 NA No_Match
```

I'm trying to use someting with `for()`, multiples `if()`, `` sapply(LIST[[i]][[j]], `%in%`, DataBase[j])) ``, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` function with `lapply` to check element in each column in both data.frames

```
DataBase$Result <- sapply(1:nrow(DataBase) ,
\(i) ifelse(all(unlist(Map(`%in%` , DataBase[i,] ,
lapply(DF1 , \(x) x)))) , "DF1", ifelse(all(unlist(Map(`%in%` , DataBase[i,] ,
lapply(DF2 , \(x) x)))) , "DF2" , "No_Match")))
```

- output

```
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5   Result
row1  4  3  1  3 NA      DF1
row2  5  5  1 10  1      DF2
row3  5  2  2  3 NA No_Match
```